# Writing a regex to match incoming chat

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression (in Python) to match inputs from a user.
I am trying to grab the "name" and the "number" from the input.

Current Regex:

```
^(?P<start_number>\d+){0,1} (?P<name>.+)|^(?P<name2>.+?)(?:\s+){0,1}(?P<end_number>\d+){0,1}$
```

Inputs are:

1. foo 1
2. foo 2 don't capture this text
3. 3 foo
4. 4 foo capture this text
5. foo 1 2 3

What I want to capture:

1. name: foo, num: 1
2. name: foo, num: 2
3. name: foo, num: 3
4. name: foo capture this text, num: 4
5. name: foo, num: 1

My issue is that due to the "$" it obviously doesn't work on 2 or 5. But if I remove the "$" it only captures the first letter of the string for 1,2,5

Any ideas? I am using regex101 to help me

Thanks

Comment: Try [`^(?:(?P<start_number>\d+) (?P<name>.+)|(?P<name2>.*?) ?(?P<end_number>\d+).*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/8pfVZR/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
^(?:(?P<start_number>\d+) (?P<name>.+)|(?P<name2>.*?) ?(?P<end_number>\d+).*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8pfVZR/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?P<start_number>\d+) (?P<name>.+)|(?P<name2>.*?) ?(?P<end_number>\d+).*)` - a non-capturing group matching 1 of 2 alternatives

  - `(?P<start_number>\d+) (?P<name>.+)` - 1+ digits (Group "start_number"), a space (may be replaced with `\s+`) and any 1+ chars other than linebreak sequence captured into Group "name"
  - `|` - or
  - `(?P<name2>.*?) ?(?P<end_number>\d+).*` - any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols captured into Group "name2", an optional space (seems like you can use `\s*` here, too) and then 1+ digits captured into Group "end_number" and then any 0+ chars up to the rest of the line
- `$` - end of string

[An online test](https://ideone.com/OVPUR9):

```
import re
s = ['foo 1',
"foo 2 don't capture this text",
'3 foo',
'4 foo capture this text',
'foo 1 2 3']
pat = r'^(?:(?P<start_number>\d+) (?P<name>.+)|(?P<name2>.*?) ?(?P<end_number>\d+).*)$'
for x in s:
    m = re.search(pat, x)
    if m and m.group("start_number"):
        print("{0}, {1}".format(m.group("start_number"), m.group("name")))
    elif m and m.group("end_number"): 
        print("{0}, {1}".format(m.group("end_number"), m.group("name2")))
```

Comment: I messed up, and forgot to mention that sometimes the number is not even there. E.G a valid input is "foo" and I need to capture that as a name.
This response works for my original question, now I am trying to edit it to match "foo" "foo bar" etc.

Comment: Perhaps, add one more alternative: [`^(?:(?P<start_number>\d+) (?P<name>.+)|(?P<name2>.*?) ?(?P<end_number>\d+).*?|(?P<name3>.*))$`](https://regex101.com/r/8pfVZR/2)